# What does it mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Precisely, I am working on the monotone convergence theorem from the book of Folland, Real analysis. Statement is as follows:

> If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^+$ such that $f_j \leq f_{j+1}$ for all $j$ and $\displaystyle f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ $\displaystyle(=\sup_n f_n)$, then $\displaystyle\int f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n$.

Then, I did not understand what does it mean taking the limit of the sequence of functions. Also, I did not understand that how it equals to the supremum. Thanks.

Comment: This is immediately related to [Dini's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem)

Comment: Thanks Peter, it was useful.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: What is the "immediate" relation?  I see that both involve monotone (pointwise) convergence, but is there any connection beyond that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is here pointwise, i.e. $f$ is the function such that $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ holds for all $x$. By assumption of monotony, the limit is also the supremum (again pointwise).

Comment: Smells like measure theory. It could be that $f$ is only the pointwise a.e. limit of the $f_n$.